# Accessing object's property from View

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Booking class inside Models folder. I already passed the Booking instance when I navigate to the class, now how do I access the Booking's property from the view?

My ViewModel:

```
public class BookingEditViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Booking Booking { get;set; }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Booking = parameters.GetValue<Booking>("booking");
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
            xmlns:booking="clr-namespace:HelloWorldPrism.Models"
            prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
            x:Class="HelloWorldPrism.Views.BookingEdit">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Booking.Id}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Booking.CustomerId}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My Model:

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

I have added the Models namespace as part of the xmlns, what do I do next to access the Booking's property?

Edit:
If I just add any value to the Booking property inside the class's constructor, the Label will print out the values.

```
    public BookingEditViewModel(BookingService bookingService, INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        this.bookingService = bookingService;
        Booking = new Booking { Id = 999, CustomerId = 2222, };
    }
```

So the problem seems to be that when the Booking is updated in OnNavigatedTo, the update isn't propagated back to the UI. I have changed the BindingMode to TwoWay, still not working. How do I solve this?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me - how is it not working, exactly? Are there any runtime errors or debug output messages?

Comment: Where are you setting `DataContext` or `BindingContext`? Is Prism doing that for you?

Comment: The view's labels isn't showing anything. The BindingContext is set-up by Prism, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Where is your `BookingViewModel`? Never ever bind to the model (unless this is a toy project)...

Comment: @Haukinger I did bind the View to the ViewModel. See my VM has a property named Booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer. Basically my issue is the same as per this question: [Prism Xamarin Forms View is not updated after changing the model in OnNavigatedTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394517/prism-xamarin-forms-view-is-not-updated-after-changing-the-model-in-onnavigatedt)

I just need to change the property to this:

```
    public Booking Booking
    {
        get => booking;
        set => SetProperty(ref booking, value);
    }
```